# MySQL if() with select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have no idea what I'm missing here:

```
IF (SELECT 'Nazwa' FROM stanowiska WHERE Nazwa LIKE = 'Lakiernik') IS NULL THEN  
INSERT INTO stanowiska (Nazwa) VALUES ('Lakiernik')
ELSE   
SELECT Nazwa FROM stanowiska WHERE Nazwa LIKE 'Lakiernik'
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What are you trying to do?  `LIKE =` isn't valid syntax, for instance.

Comment: Could you post your error message if any?

Comment: I want to check if the record exists. If no, I want to insert it. If yes, I just want to select it.

Comment: `I have no idea what I'm missing here:` - a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be what you want:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM stanowiska WHERE Nazwa = 'Lakiernik') THEN  
    INSERT INTO stanowiska (Nazwa)
        VALUES ('Lakiernik');
ELSE SELECT Nazwa FROM stanowiska WHERE Nazwa = 'Lakiernik'
END IF;
```

Even this is really strange.  The code block is inserting in the `THEN` and return a value in the `ELSE`.  That doesn't seem right.  And, the part being returned is just `Lakiernik`, so I don't think the `ELSE` is needed:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM stanowiska WHERE Nazwa = 'Lakiernik') THEN  
    INSERT INTO stanowiska (Nazwa)
        VALUES ('Lakiernik');
END IF;
```

However, this has race conditions.  So, if you want to prevent duplicates, the right way is:

```
create unique index unq_stanowiska_nazwa on stanowiska(nazwa);
```

Then:

```
    INSERT INTO stanowiska (Nazwa)
        VALUES ('Lakiernik')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nazwa = VALUES(Nazwa);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that answer. Works perfect

Answer (score 0):

Try this, didn't test it yet:

```
IF (SELECT 1 FROM stanowiska WHERE Nazwa = 'Lakiernik') 
THEN  
INSERT INTO stanowiska (Nazwa) VALUES ('Lakiernik');
ELSE   
SELECT Nazwa FROM stanowiska WHERE Nazwa ='Lakiernik';
END IF;
```

Comment: it shows an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (SELECT 1 FROM stanowiska WHERE Nazwa = 'Lakiernik') 
THEN  
INSERT INTO stan' at line 1